# Spring Cloud gateway is timing out in 30s,

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm using spring cloud gateway as my gateway application. When I try to call the api directly it succeeds, but when called through it times out in 30s.I'm trying to upload a multipart file which is around 250MB. directly calling the application it succeeds in around 6-7 minutes.

Spring cloud api gateway timeout configuration

```
- id:  xyz
          uri: ${xyz.----}
          predicates:
            - Path=/${xyz}/**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/${xyz}/(?<oldPath>.*), /${oldPath}
            - CachingRequestBody
            - SignResponseBody
            - name: RequestSize
              args:
               maxSize: 1024MB
          metadata:
            response-timeout: 600000
            connect-timeout: 600000
            serviceName: ${xyz}




public Customizer<ReactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory> defaultCustomizer() {
        return factory -> factory.configureDefault(id -> new Resilience4JConfigBuilder(id)
                .circuitBreakerConfig(CircuitBreakerConfig.ofDefaults())
                .timeLimiterConfig(TimeLimiterConfig.custom().timeoutDuration(Duration.ofMillis(600000)).build())
                .build());



cloud:
    gateway:
      httpclient:
        connect-timeout: 600000
        response-timeout: 600s
      default-filters:
        - name: OrderedCircuitBreaker
          args:
            name: global-fallback
            fallbackUri: forward:/fallback
```

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: is there spring keyword on top of the structure at httpclient configuration? Check out here https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/#http-timeouts-configuration

Answer (score 0):

Hi Guys I found the answer,
Every request in gateway goes through a set of filter. as you can see a filter CachedRequestBody. this filter caches the request body. which in case was very large and api gateway didn't have space for that so it timeout with java heap space error. I removed that filter and now it's working fine. Thanks

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to explain how you remove it ?